# Cannot deserialize Json

Tags: c#, json, parsing, serialization, gdax-api

I need help I can't deserialize my json

```
 var myWebClient = new WebClient();
 var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var json = myWebClient.DownloadString("https://api.gdax.com/products/btc-usd/book?level=2");
 OrderBookContainerExmo container = js.Deserialize<OrderBookContainerExmo>(json);
```

I'm getting:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.dll

Additional information:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

On this line:

```
var json = myWebClient.DownloadString("https://api.gdax.com/products/btc-usd/book?level=2");
```

Comment: Have a look at the raw message using eg fiddler and you will see: `{"message":"User-Agent header is required."}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was mentioned in comment, you need to add User-Agent to headers.

```
var myWebClient = new WebClient();
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
myWebClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
var json = myWebClient.DownloadString("https://api.gdax.com/products/btc-usd/book?level=2");
OrderBookContainerExmo container = js.Deserialize<OrderBookContainerExmo>(json);
```